# Magento 1.7 - Invoice modification

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have been looking though just about all `app/code/mage` files trying to find out where I can remove the customers telephone number from the invoices.

The closest I think I got was to remove some code in the config.xml file in the `app/code/mage/customer/etc/` directory, or the `/app/code/mage/directory/model/country.php` but no change I made in there did anything (I know I should avoid making changes to the core, but It's on a dev site and I just wanted to see where to change it).

I have tried clearing the cache after each change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ps. I am using Magento 1.7.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the phone # go to Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Address Template

Comment: Thanks! How could I've missed it!